# android app crashes on many clicks on EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I made an app with same layouts with EditTexts and textview,I posted the code from xml at bottom,it works fine if I try to write something in it but if one edittext is clicked for many times the app crashes and this is the logcat

```
03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ActionBarContextView can only be used with android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView.onMeasure(ActionBarContextView.java:426)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12922)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1385)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:670)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:563)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12922)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2261)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12922)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12922)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1385)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:670)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:563)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12922)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12922)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:594)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:376)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12922)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1399)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:367)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12922)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:594)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:376)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12922)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12922)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at 
android.view.View.measure(View.java:12922)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
            03-18 12:09:43.007: E/AndroidRuntime(13064):    at
```

and this is the xml file

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_center"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:layout_width="0dip" 
android:layout_height="0dip"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textNume"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="NUME SI PRENUME"
        android:textColor="@color/MenuDarkGrey"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtNume"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorTitlu"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textCNP"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CNP"
            android:textColor="@color/MenuDarkGrey"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/wrong_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/exclamare_atentionare" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtCNP"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:inputType="number|textCapWords"
        android:maxLength="25"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorTitlu"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textJudLoc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="JUDET,LOCALITATE"
        android:textColor="@color/MenuDarkGrey"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtJudLoc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorTitlu"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textAdresa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="ADRESA"
        android:textColor="@color/MenuDarkGrey"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtAdresa"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorTitlu"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTelefon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="TELEFON"
        android:textColor="@color/MenuDarkGrey"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtTelefon"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:inputType="number|textCapWords"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorTitlu"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="EMAIL"
        android:textColor="@color/MenuDarkGrey"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/wrong_textmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/exclamare_atentionare" />

    </RelativeLayout>



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtEmail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:lines="1"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorTitlu"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/renunta"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_renunta"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            android:text="Renunta"
            android:textColor="@color/MenuLightGrey"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/salveaza"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/button_salveaza"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            android:text="Salveaza"
            android:textColor="@color/MenuLightGrey"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

and code from class

```
            edtNume = (EditText)findViewById (R.id.edtNume);
        edtNume.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) 
            {
                if (hasFocus == true)
                {
                  ContulMeu.tooltip.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE); 
                  ContulMeu.tvTooltip.setText ("Completeaza numele si prenumele");
                }else{
                    ContulMeu.tvTooltip.setText ("");
                     ContulMeu.tooltip.setVisibility (View.GONE); 
                }
            }
        });


        edtCnp = (EditText)findViewById (R.id.edtCNP);
        edtCnp.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) 
            {
                if (hasFocus == true)
                {
                  ContulMeu.tooltip.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE); 
                  ContulMeu.tvTooltip.setText ("Codul numeric personal");
                }else{
                    ContulMeu.tvTooltip.setText ("");
                     ContulMeu.tooltip.setVisibility (View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

        edtCnp.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                if (edtCnp.getText().toString().length()!=13 || !YTOUtils.verificaCNP(edtCnp.getText().toString()))
                     ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wrong_text)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 else ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wrong_text)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });


        edtJudLoc = (EditText)findViewById (R.id.edtJudLoc);    
        edtJudLoc.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (edtCnp.getText().toString().length()!=13 || !YTOUtils.verificaCNP(edtCnp.getText().toString()))
                     ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wrong_text)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 else ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wrong_text)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    salveaza=false;//nu salvez cand trebuie setat judetul
                    Lista.tipDate = "judete";
                    Intent i = new Intent (DespreMine.this,Lista.class);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    startActivity (i);

            }
        });
        edtJudLoc.setFocusable(false);
        edtAdresa = (EditText)findViewById (R.id.edtAdresa);
        edtAdresa.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) 
            {
                if (hasFocus == true)
                {
                  ContulMeu.tooltip.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE); 
                  ContulMeu.tvTooltip.setText ("Adresa completa din buletin");
                }else{
                    ContulMeu.tvTooltip.setText ("");
                     ContulMeu.tooltip.setVisibility (View.GONE); 
                }
            }
        });
        edtTelefon = (EditText)findViewById (R.id.edtTelefon);
        edtTelefon.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) 
            {
                if (hasFocus == true)
                {
                  ContulMeu.tooltip.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE); 
                  ContulMeu.tvTooltip.setText ("Numarul tau de telefon la care poti fi contactat");
                }else{
                    ContulMeu.tvTooltip.setText ("");
                     ContulMeu.tooltip.setVisibility (View.GONE); 
                }
            }
        });
        edtEmail = (EditText)findViewById (R.id.edtEmail);
        edtEmail.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) 
            {
                if (hasFocus == true)
                {
                  ContulMeu.tooltip.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
                  ContulMeu.tvTooltip.setText ("Adresa de e-mail la care poti fi contactat");
                }else{
                        ContulMeu.tvTooltip.setText ("");
                     ContulMeu.tooltip.setVisibility (View.GONE); 
                     edtEmail.setText(YTOUtils.replaceInEmail(edtEmail.getText().toString()));
                }
            }
        });

        edtEmail.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                if (!YTOUtils.eMailValidation(edtEmail.getText().toString()))
                     ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wrong_textmail)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 else ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wrong_textmail)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        load();

        btn_renunta = (Button) findViewById (R.id.renunta);
        btn_renunta.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                salveaza=false;
                finish ();

            }
        });

        btn_salveaza = (Button) findViewById (R.id.salveaza);
        btn_salveaza.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                salveaza=false;//daca salveaza=true salvez si la onPause()
                AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> saveContactTask = 
                       new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() 
                       {
                          @Override
                          protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
                          {

                             saveContact();
                             return null;
                          }

                          @Override
                          protected void onPostExecute(Object result) 
                          {
                             finish();
                          }
                       }; 

                    saveContactTask.execute((Object[]) null); 
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) 
                            getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edtTelefon.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
        });

        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "ArialRoundedMT.ttf");

        edtNume.setTypeface(Typeface.create(tf,Typeface.BOLD));
        edtCnp.setTypeface(Typeface.create(tf,Typeface.BOLD));
        edtJudLoc.setTypeface(Typeface.create(tf,Typeface.BOLD));
        edtAdresa.setTypeface(Typeface.create(tf,Typeface.BOLD));
        edtTelefon.setTypeface(Typeface.create(tf,Typeface.BOLD));
        edtEmail.setTypeface(Typeface.create(tf,Typeface.BOLD));

    }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Any code to share?

Comment: I've added the code from the activity

Comment: No one is going to plough through all that code. Post only relevant code.

Comment: i really don't know which is relevant and which is not

Answer (score 0):

I think error in this :

```
<LinearLayout
android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:layout_width="0dip" 
android:layout_height="0dip"/>
```

Change it to

```
    <LinearLayout
android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Hope this helped you.